# AR core and Unity Build Issues

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore

*Version: 2018.4.5f1 LTS*

I have been given a project that use AR core (not sure but i think its AR core legacy) to place furniture. I have to add functionality of photogrammetry (scanning furniture and make its 3d models).

but unfortunately, not able to run the initial project.
[image]

The app does not run on device (dont know what the issue android SDKs or this AR core is causing it)

[image]

On Build & run (Ctrl + B)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem lies with the downloaded SDK using Android Studio.
My unity 2021 was building android 13 app perfectly fine, So I thought to give that a try. And yes chosing the unity 2021 SDK made unity 2018 build andriod 13 app